# Finding subdirectory WordPress database in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I am currently developing a WordPress site in a sub directory of a domain (`mydomain.com/testing/newwordpresssite`), hosted by GoDaddy.

I need to access the WP database for this site through PHPMyAdmin, but it is not listed when I go to PHPMyAdmin through GoDaddy. `wp-config.php` says that `DB_HOST` is `localhost,` so I would think the problem is that the database is in a subdirectory, making PHPMyAdmin unable to access it. Is there a setting I can change to fix this?

Comment: have you manually installed wp on or using option given by godaddy ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't the one to install it - I'm just making the final changes. As mentioned below, I think I'll have to go back to the client to get in touch with their domain manager and/or the person who installed this instance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was a question for GoDaddy support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, and had nothing to do with phpMyAdmin or WordPress problems. It appears that the problem was on GoDaddy's end, and after contacting tech support, they were able to run a script that allowed the database to appear in cPanel, as well as the appropriate user, that I could then assign to the database. It's now accessible in phpMyAdmin. Apologies that I can't be more precise about what was wrong on GoDaddy's end, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

the DB will not be in a sub directory, that is not how it works. If the DB says localhost, it has to be there. Be sure to expand the DB list on the right like so:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not there (my view doesn't even have an expand option). I'm realizing it's probably not an issue with phpMyAdmin, since under cPanel, when simply viewing MySQL databases, the one I'm looking for is not even listed. So I guess I'll need to go back the client, and investigate their hosting setup.